# Minimizing Garbage Collection in Java Attempt (with example)

Tags: java, object, memory

q(aside - I'm not sure what the term is for objects that are created but not stored in a variable).

I don't really know how to word my question well, so I'll illustrate it.

Example one with two objects declared:

```
Random random = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i += 1){
    Integer integer = new Integer(random.nextInt());
    String string = integer.toString();
}
```

Example two with only one object declared:

```
Random random = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i += 1){
    String string = (new Integer(random.nextInt())).toString();
}
```

In the second example, the Integer object is still created, but its location in memory is not saved (I think). I know that decreasing object creation by one seems insignificant, but in a large loop with many iterations, halving the object references would certainly be beneficial. Does this technique save any memory (i.e. minimize Garbage Collection)?

**Edit:** Changed the example to better illustrate the question.

Comment: Probably you want to show a better example than this.

Comment: Both of these cases create the *exact same* number/type of objects. The local variables are irrelevant for sake of memory usage here. Also, using `Integer.valueOf(5)` would be "better" as it will often use a cache and avoid creating a new Integer object entirely (there are many SO questions on this topic).

Comment: While there is a *subtle* issue here due to local variables being *GC roots* (although it's incredibly moot for the small immutable Integer type in question), this is *irrelevant* if these variables appear in a loop. The *exact same* number/type of *objects* are created; neither the variables nor the extra assignment "add" new objects.

Comment: The simple solution here would be to avoid creating the Integer at all, you don't need it.  Then you can remove the need to create a String (depending on what you doing with) and you are creating no garbage at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this technique save any memory (i.e. minimize Garbage Collection)?

In fact you are asking two different questions.  The answers are "No (in practice)", and "No".

(This applies to both the original and updated versions of the Question.)

---

The first answer requires a little explaining.

In the first example, if this is in a loop, then the `string` and `integer` variables are either going to go out of scope many times, or they are going to be overwritten many times.  (In your example, they go out of scope.)

If either of those happens, the current values of the variables are going to be "forgotten" and the corresponding objects are going to become unreachable.

In the second example, you don't put the `Integer` object into a variable, so the corresponding object might become unreachable a few nanoseconds earlier.  But since this code is in a loop, the difference is negligible.  In fact, it is probably unmeasurable.

---

The second answer is easier to explain.  Your code is only going to *trigger* garbage collection if one of the two allocations (i.e. the `new` statement that creates the `Integer` or the one inside `Integer.toString()` that creates the `String`) needs more memory than is immediately available.  Since both bits of code do the same allocations, there is no difference in the *number of times* the GC will be run.

---

The other point is that it is simply a waste of time to think about these things at this level of detail in Java.  In general, the garbage collector just takes care of things.  In this specific example, the maximum theoretical advantage of the "optimization" is that a single `Integer` object might be freed on garbage collection cycle earlier.  That object occupies in the order of 16 bytes.  It is simply not worth even thinking about.

What you are doing is known in the trade as "premature optimization".  Don't waste your time on it.  If you need to optimize, wait until you have a working program, and profile it.  Then spend your energy on the parts that the profiler says are problems.

Answer (score 1):

Whether it is one of two approaches, in both approach there are two objects created in scope of single iteration. Once an iteration completes both are eligible for `gc`.

Now, IMO GC `minor cycle` (in this specific case of short lived objects) wouldn't be per iteration and will happen when related space is full with GCed objects (check with `jstat -gcutil`), it doesn't matter which approach you choose as both would give you similar memory stats.

Answer (score 0):

This is a premature optimization and you probably won't ever actually need to do this.

But, yes. As long as `integer` never goes out of scope, it will never be garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

Objects which are not **reachable** would be eligible for garbage collection(in your case `new Integer(5)`)

Refer to [Tuning Garbage Collection](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/gc-tuning-5-138395.html) but i doubt you would ever need to do it

Comment: I am always curious by how Java handles: `void f() { X x = new X(); while(forALongTime) { .. }; }` but have never quite seem to find it focused on. Can `x` be reclaimed *before* the function exists? It *can* be in C#/CLR. Under my understanding of reachability roots in Java, it's not possible for the same "early" reclaiming .. but is this guaranteed? Anyway, an Integer being reachable is hardly exciting :D

Comment: `integer` *is* reachable.

Comment: @user2246674 No. `x` is reachable in the `while` loop, so it cannot be reclaimed.